# Makefile linking against a library

Tags: c, makefile

I have the following makefile.I have the shared library `lcustom` in the path /usr/local/lib. I am using the functions from that library in my program `test.y` but it is giving undefined reference for the functions defined in `libcustom.so`.What is wrong with my makefile below.

```
all: test


test.tab.c test.tab.h:  test.y
        bison -d test.y

lex.yy.c: test.l test.tab.h
        flex test.l

test: lex.yy.c test.tab.c test.tab.h test_util.c 
        gcc -lcustom -o test test.tab.c test_util.c lex.yy.c 

clean:
    rm test test.tab.c lex.yy.c test.tab.h
```

Comment: `nm /usr/local/lib/libcustom.so | grep your_function_name` what did you see?

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr - I get `0000000000001ef0 T my_func_name`.

Comment: related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been long time since last time I write a serious `makefile`, please point it out if I am wrong.

there are ways to avoid encounter such issue by using implicit rules:

```
.PHONY: all clean

LDFLAGS=-lcustom
CFLAGS= # your gcc options start here

all: test

test.tab.c test.tab.h:  test.y
        bison -d test.y

lex.yy.c: test.l test.tab.h
        flex test.l

lex.yy.o: lex.yy.c

tast.tab.o: test.tab.c test.tab.h

test_util.o: test_util.c

test: lex.yy.o test.tab.o test_util.o

clean:
    rm -f test test.tab.c lex.yy.c test.tab.h *.o
```

then you avoided all painful stuff.

in general, it's better to generate `.o` files explicitly then use linker to deal with them, such that if a build fails, you will definite know what's wrong with it, specifically compile time error, or linker error.

about the cause of your question, I think you should put `-lcustom` in a correct position to make it work. I rarely see people put `-l` flag right after `gcc` so I am pretty sure it's not correct. I would guess you should put it at the very end.

PS: in my comment, `nm` is a tool to list out the symbols in a object file. specifically, in your output, `T` means the function is in text segment and it's exported so it should be able to be linked. check `man nm` for more info.

Comment: you assessment about putting the `-l` option at the end does work.thanks.

Comment: I agree that your way of organizing the makefile is more readable.

Comment: I don't see gcc option there?

Comment: @liv2hak that's good. i haven't written c program for quite a while and i found i lost a lot of memory about it so i wasn't so sure.

Comment: @liv2hak gcc option can be passed by `CFLAGS`. the makefile i showed uses `implicit rules`, which let `make` generate the rules automatically for you. in this case, it auto-generates rules for `gcc` and `ld`, so you don't code them out yourself.